# Selenium headless not reading menu

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written selenium code that works fine when running non headless chromedriver.

It find the navbar and the items within.  However when i run headless it finds a navbar, but there is no content and the displayed property is false.
I have already added a 50 second sleep to exclude the page not being ready but this did not change anything

```
private string[] findAllPortalMenuItems()
        {
            List<string> anchors = new List<string>();

            var navbars = _driver.FindElements(By.TagName("nav"));
            foreach (var navbar in navbars)
            {
                if (navbar.Displayed)
                {
                    var menu = navbar.FindElement(By.TagName("ul")); //get the horizontal menu
                    //var mainLis = menu.FindElements(By.TagName("li"));
                    var mainLis = menu.FindElements(By.XPath("./li"));
                    foreach (var li in mainLis) //this finds all the main menu items
                    {
                        var subMenu = li.FindElement(By.TagName("ul")); //get the vertical menu
                        var subLis = subMenu.FindElements(By.TagName("li"));
                        foreach (var subLi in subLis) //get all the sub menu items
                        {
                            var anchor = subLi.FindElement(By.TagName("a"));
                            var href = anchor.GetAttribute("href");
                            if (!href.Contains("Logout", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) anchors.Add(anchor.GetAttribute("href"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return anchors.ToArray();
        }
```

so in essence it finds 1 navbar, which is correct, the non headless also finds 1 navbar.  But in headless mode it does not find any menu entries, and the displayed is false.

this is how i start the selenium driver:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArgument("--headless");
            options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
            options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", downloadsPath);
            options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1);
            options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
```

Comment: Can you share the application url?

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: unfortunately i cannot share the application url as it is an internal accessible website only, as well as you need to login to proceed.

There also is no error ... it simply find an empty navbar which is not visible according to headless mode.  while not headless it works perfect

Comment: @Thierry Verhaegen try to run with the incognito mode "--incognito"

options.addArguments("--incognito")

Comment: didn't do anything :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
```

to your driver options in headless mode.
Default screen size in headless mode is small so that many elements appearing in normal mode are not visible in headless mode until you define the screen size as maximized or set it to some other big enough size.

Comment: This did not help unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a strict windows size, for example

```
options.AddArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
```